# I can’t update but I can install apps (App Store)

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I can access the Japanese App Store and I can install the apps but when it comes to updating, it says “App has been removed by the developer from the app store.” (Which is not as my friends had already updated their games.)

My region is in Japan (both in the app store and the apple site) and I have never switched it to any country.

The only “fix” I found when one of my apps were like this, was to uninstall and reinstall, which isn’t favorable right now as my data will be lost once I uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the developer has changed the bundle-ID of the application, which essential makes it a completely new app - just with the same name. This could explain why you cannot update your app that has the old bundle-ID, whereas other user's who downloaded the newer app with the new bundle-ID can.

This can happen for example when a company that owns an app sells that app to another developer. In certain cases, they need to use a new bundle identifier.